# Test task on concurrency

Tags: concurrency

The question is:

Global variable x has initial value 0. In the system there are 2 concurrent processes going on with the following code:

```
process P;
var i: integer;
begin
   for i := 1 to 5 do x := x+ 1;
end;
```

After executing both processes x has value of ...

A.    =10

B.    >=5

C.    <10

there can be more than 1 answer correct.
So I think it is A and B but could someone explain how the process executes behind the scenes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When two processes handle the same data, it is all about when one process reads a variable and when it writes a value.

If two two processes read *x* at the same time for the first time, they will both see the value of *x* as 0. When the first process writes the new value of *x* it will be 1, but when the second process writes the value of *x* it will also be 1. If the two process get out of sync it is possible that the first process reads the value of *x* and writes it, and then the second process will read *x* and write *x*. In the latter case *x* will be incremented by 2 instead of 1.

So answer B will always be true, because even if the two processes would read *x* at the same time, it will be incremented 5 times.

Answer A will only be true when the two processes read and write *x* one after another.
Answer C is true in all other cases.